# How to tell if a response from the backend originated in a Varnish cache lookup

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Is there a way to tell, at a point in the varnish subroutines when you have write access to the response object, whether the object was passed to the backend directly, or first sent through a cache lookup?  Right now I am fiddling around with adding application logic to receive some header and then send it back, which can be read by varnish, but I would prefer to have the varnish behaviour be a bit more application independent.

What I'm looking for would be something like the below, though the method where I //DoSomeStuff doesn't have to be the deliver.

```
sub vcl_recv {  
 if( req.url ~ "^/something/ignored.*$" ) {
   return ( pass );
 }
 else {  
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return( hash );
  }
}
sub vcl_deliver {
 if( resp.lookup == 1 ) {
   //Do Some Stuff
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there multiple ways. you can hook in `vcl_hash{}` and add some custom header there in `req.`, you can do the same in `vcl_pass{}`, you can do that one step before in `vcl_recv{}`, or one step after in `vcl_hit{}` and `vcl_miss{}` (note that a `hit-for-pass` calls `vcl_pass{}` also)

Look up the [processing states](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/states.html#client-side) to get your picture clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent varnish-cache versions, [bereq.uncacheable](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vcl-var.html?highlight=bereq.uncacheable#bereq) gives you the answer.